# Can I compare a questionnaire answer with an "ideal" percentage?

Tags: survey

I have a questionnaire mostly consisted of Likert questions. For each question I am provided with an "ideal" answer (which is 100% for a specific choice).

For example, let's say Question 10 has four choices and choice (a) should be 100% but it isn't. Can I run a statistical test to see if that question differs from 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, for example, with [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). It allows to compare an observed distribution with a theoretical distribution (which is $(1, 0,0,0)$ in your case). In [r](/questions/tagged/r), this would be something like:

```r
dat <- c(90, 5, 4, 1)
chisq.test(dat, p = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Note that if you do this for many items, you may run into problems with [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).